# Command Key combinations not working with VNC viewer

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

So I followed the advice of the below answer to attempt to remote into my Mac mini from Ubuntu 16.04 with VNC Viewer. Everything is working fine except for <kbd>Command</kbd> key combos.

- [Can I remotely access my Mac from Linux using screen sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84221/can-i-remotely-access-my-mac-from-linux-using-screen-sharing/84228#84228)

While attempting to troubleshoot, I opened the keyboard viewer, which is showing me that <kbd>Command</kbd> keys are being detected when pressed alone, but when pressed in combination with other keys, the last key pressed overrides it. According to the keyboard viewer, other key combinations do work as well.

I am open to using a different VNC program, but I don't know which if any will fix this problem.

**UPDATE:** It works in full screen, but not otherwise

Comment: Which OS and VNC software are you using here? Linux/Remmina, as in the linked post?

Comment: @ChrisLarson Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: command combos work for me with Real VNC server and client.  The client is free. There is a free server version for home use.  I'd start with the free client.