# Log into Mac from Ubuntu over VNC

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I know there are so many tutorials and solutions are posted on internet regarding this, but I am unable to solve my issue.

I am using Ubuntu on my desktop and I also wanna access my MacBook (MacOS mojave 10.14.6) within local network. I followed “Sharing” preference panel and checked the box next to “Remote management” then “Computer Settings…” and made “VNC viewers may control screen with password” checked and set a simple password.

[image]

[image]

But I am having authentication issues while accessing from Ubuntu, It asks me username and password, I am putting same password which I set previously on mac configurations.
[image]

[image]

[image]

But IDK which username is needed to be put here, I tried so many like mac username, mac pc name, Ubuntu username even tried to keep it empty but it's not working, it's showing always authentication error, How do I solve this? Am I missing anything?

Comment: [You need to specify higher color depth](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307442/371963)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have solved my problem by simply installing [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/), before it I was using Remmina. Now it's working fine without prompting for user name. But it has very poor performance.

I also found another solution for my issue is TeamViewer on LAN, and it's much better than VNC Viewer in terms of speed.