# Remotely access Mac from Linux using krdc

Tags: macos, unix, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Following up on [Can I remotely access my Mac from Linux using screen sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84221/)

- I've set up the Mac to be Accessed Remotely via VNC
- I am trying to remotely access it from Linux using `krdc`

which I am blocked by this prompt

[image]

Do I need a user name to access VNC?
I'm sure my Password is correct, just I've tried everything for the User name part, but nothing works.

PS, as how I enabled VNC, I'm following exactly as instructed from [Can I remotely access my Mac from Linux using screen sharing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84221/)

> This is pretty simple, you'll need to go to System Preferences → Screen Sharing and then click on **Computer Settings**. From there you can select **VNC viewers may control screen with password:** and supply a password.

[image]

Comment: How did you set up remote access on Mac?

Comment: @nohillside, just follow the https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84221/. You can't go wrong on that.

Comment: Well, apparently something isn’t working as expected in your case so it might be important to know how exactly you configured remote access on your Mac.

Comment: See updated OP @nohillside.

Comment: I got into the same problem using Vinagre client

Comment: I hava supplied password, but it download me to type just password in client. It asks for user, did you fill it up?